# variables and jquery: how capture value (part 1)

Tags: jquery, variables, html-lists

I must capture a value in a `<ul><li>` list.

I do so:

```
function capture(){

    $('#country_list li a').mouseover(function(a){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var $regionMap = '#'+ $(this).attr('id');
    alert($regionMap); // control
    });

    $('#country_list li a').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('selected');

    }); 
}
```

and `selected` CSS class is this

```
.selected 
    {
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

The function is ok and I activate in HTML the function with:

```
<ul id="country_list" style="list-style-type:none" onmouseover="capture();">
```

I'm not sure that this is correct. Do you have any help for me?

I have posted a second question, more important, linked with this, and the name is:

variables and jquery: how capture value and use them (part 2)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds perfectly ok, just you could replace the css manipulation with a css like

```
#country_list li a:hover {
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: oh, thanks! the English is beautiful (mine not!)."Sounds" is a fantastic way to describe your point of view. In italian we have a lot of expressions to describe a point of view, but nothing like " to sound"! Fantastic! Bye

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the use of the 'onmouseover' attribute, and applying the event listener directly with JS instead, this will ensure the HTML is more clean and the JS is completely separated from the HTML.

HTML

```
<ul id="country_list">
```

CSS

```
#country_list {
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

JS

```
var $country_list = $( '#country_list' );

$country_list.mouseover( function (e) {

    $( e.target ).addClass( 'selected' );

    var $regionMap = '#' + e.target.id;

    alert( $regionMap ); // control

});

$country_list.mouseout( function (e) {

    $( e.target ).removeClass( 'selected' );

});
```

Comment: @Ulisse: "e" is a variable referring to the event object which is generated when an event is fired and the event handle catch it. It's an object containing informations about the event. For example "e.target" is the element which generated the event.

Comment: ok thanks. I'm studing your code and this is a better way probably, so I think that Iwould like to use it, but it doesn't seem to work and Firebug give me this message"uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $regionMap". I have tried so also, but the problem is always there:  var $regionMap = '#' + e.target.attr('id'); . Thanks for the answer about "e" variable.