# variables and jquery: how capture value and use them (part 2)

Tags: jquery, variables, loops, global-variables

this is my problem:

I have captured a variable from a ul-li list

I have a list with a lot of names: *Roma, Milano, Venezia ...*
I capture the id value of these (pulsante1 for Roma, pulsante2 for Milano, pulsante3 for Venezia, ... ) with a mouseover event (look for this question *[variables and jquery: how capture value (part 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398454/variables-and-jquery-how-capture-value-part-1)* if you want to know more).

So, I have now a global variable called $regionMap, and the its content changes every time the ul-li list has a mouseover event.
So, now I could use *$regionMap* value instead of the different id values (*pulsante1, pulsante2, pulsante3...*) in other jquery scripts.

For example I have this loop:

```
$('#pulsante1').mousedown(function() // when click over pulsante1 (id value for "Roma")
        {           
var $variab=document.getElementById('pulsante1').innerHTML; // take the name (here Roma)
var $alfa="#"+ $variab;  // Roma is now #Roma
alert("You entered: " + $alfa); //control
dialog($alfa); // calling the function dialog rolling on #Roma value.
});

// here is similar at the first but instead #pulsante1(Roma) you have #pulsante2 (Milano)
$('#pulsante2').mousedown(function() 
        {       
        var $variab=document.getElementById('pulsante2').innerHTML;
        var $alfa="#"+ $variab;
        alert("You entered: " + $alfa); //control
        dialog($alfa); // calling the function dialog
        }); 
                    });//close click
```

Now, I would like use *$regionMap* instead pulsante1, pulsante2... but for me is impossible!
I try so `$($regionMap).mousedown(function()` and in other way (  `$($regionMap)., ($regionMap)., $('$regionMap').` .... ),

but I have always no results! How can I do? You know how pass a variable?

I think that probably there  is a better way to obtain similar result (for example with a loop *for in *) but I don't know how to it...

Sorry for my long post and sorry for the basical english, but I'm not a developer and I have gone in a big TILT!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your other question, try this.

```
$('#country_list').mousedown( function( e ) {

  // e.target is the element you clicked

  var $variab = e.target.innerHTML;

  var $alfa= '#' + $variab;  // Roma is now #Roma

  alert("You entered: " + $alfa); //control

  dialog($alfa);

});
```

Your `#country_list` element will listen for any mousedown events. When one occurs, you are able to find the element who generated the event with `e.target`.

Comment: ok. I have used this your solution mixed to others. You can see it in the last part of my questions called variables and jquery: how capture value and use them (part 3). I have some questions to tell.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like...

```
$( $regionMap ).each( function (i,el)
{
    $( el ).mousedown(function() // when click over pulsante1 (id value for "Roma")
        {           
            var $variab=el.innerHTML; // take the name
            var $alfa="#"+ $variab;  // Roma is now #Roma
            alert("You entered: " + $alfa); //control
            dialog($alfa); // calling the function dialog rolling on #Roma value.
        });

});
```

This will loop through each of the ids in regionMap and apply the callback function to each one.

The jQuery each function applies the callback function to each item in the collection.  the collection in this case is your list of ids. ['#pulsante1','#pulsante2']

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: You are creating an event listener for each element, what about if there are a thousand of elements? Since events bubble up, you need only a single event listener for them all.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to bind all the events:

```
$($regionMap).children('li').mousedown(function()
{           
    alert("You entered: " + this.id);
    dialog(this.id);
});
```

This will bind the event to each li inside the map, and they will handle the event separately.

Comment: Thanks, but I have problems to use variable external of a single script. I declared a global variable ($regionMap), but it resulted always undefinited. I have another post in which I treat the question,   how capture value and use them (part 3)