# variables and jquery: how capture value and use them (part 3)

Tags: jquery, global-variables, html-lists

ok guys,
I have had a last post about the question *variables and jquery: how capture value and use them (part 3)*. You can find other questions about looking for *variables and jquery: how capture value and use them (part 1)* and *variables and jquery: how capture value and use them (part 2)*.

I had to do:
1. capture a value from an ul-li list;
2. insert it into a global variable (*not has been successful*);
3. use this variable for another click function.

Now I present my solution code (with the helps of the community) that sounds, but I would like to optimize it.

I have a ul-li list of cities with an event mouseover:

```
<ul id="country_list" onmouseover="cl();">
        <li><a id="pulsante1" href="#">Roma</a>
        <li><a id="pulsante2" href="#">Milano</a>
        <li><a id="pulsante3" href="#">Venezia</a
```

this is my CSS:

```
.selected 
     {
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     }
```

begin the function, with comment:

```
 function cl(){
     $('.map').maphilight(); // call a plug-in to illuminate the maps

       $('#country_list li a').mouseover(function(e){ //on mouseover over the list

    // change background color at the element of the list over the mouse is 
       $( e.target ).addClass('selected');  

    //put id value in a variable. I'm going to capture pulsante1 for example more #
        var $regionMap = '#' + e.target.id; 

    // put the value 
        var $variab = '#'+ e.target.innerHTML;

           //control
        //alert(regionMap);
        // alert (variab);

// this part is the plugin for highlight some particular areas (the cities' areas). form here to...
          $($regionMap).mouseover(function(a) {
            $($variab).mouseover();
            });
            $($regionMap).mouseout(function(a) {
            $($variab).mouseout();
            }); 
        });
//... here

//remove background color 
        $('#country_list li a').mouseout(function(e){
         $( e.target ).removeClass('selected');
        });     

// mousedown function. 
         $('#country_list li a').mousedown( function(e) {

         // e.target is the element you clicked, give me HTML value (Roma for example) 

        var $variabile = e.target.innerHTML;

    var $alfa= '#' + $variabile;  // Roma is now #Roma  

      // alert("You entered: " + $alfa); //control

    //control   dialog($alfa); // this call a dialog function giving its *$alfa* value
     });
    }
```

ok. this are my problems:

1. I don't like use onmouseover here `<ul id="country_list" onmouseover="cl();">` but it doesn't seem work in other way ('#country_list').mouseover doesn't work
   Ideas?
2. I would like divide the function cl() for the part relative at mousedown. For this I need have two global variables with the value of:

   a. *id li* (for example *pulsante1*). For me this should be *regionMap*.
   b. *name li* (for example *Roma*). For me this should be *variab*.

but I don't know the way to obtain a global variable!
I have declared them in the `<head></head>` between `<script>` `regionMap=""; variab="";`

I have tryed whit $ in front, and in a lot of other ways but all my tentatives have been unfulfilled...

So you have help for me?

Thanks

Comment: [Part 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398454/variables-and-jquery-how-capture-value-part-1) and [Part 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398750/variables-and-jquery-how-capture-value-and-use-them-part-2)?

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem

instead of using the onmouseover attribute it is better to bind the mouseover event to the jQuery object. You can do that by using the following code:

```
$('ul#country_list').bind('mouseover', function () { // do what you want to do on mouse over });
```

You can also first define a function and then use that as the second argument for the bind function. For example:

```
var cl = function () { // do something };
$('ul#country_list').bind('mouseover', cl);
```

Then your second problem, im not sure what you mean with "the part relative at mousedown".
But for global variables you can do this in different ways.

What I always like to do (note this is an example of doing it not a standard):

Create an empty object within the window variable for example:

```
window.globals = {};
function test () {
    window.globals.test = 'this is available everywhere!';
}
test();
console.log(window.globals);
```

Comment: ok Jeffreydev.
I have understood.
For the first question all is ok, and I'll go to use your suggestion, but you have an explanation very nice for *bind()?*. I use it but I don't understand very well its. second question (sorry for my English): I would like divide the function in two:
the first for mouseover event and te second for mousedown event, and my problem is to "capture" a variable in the mouseover function and use it in the mousedown function. I will try, thanks. ulisse